# How can I hide the folder where web service application hosted?

Tags: web-services, security, iis

There is a web service application hosted On IIS 7.5. Authentication mode is Windows. When calling web services through my application, useDefaultCredentials atttribute on web service client is false. So web service call made on behaf of anonymous user. And also anonymous authentication mode enabled on IIS for the web service application.

To call web services successfully, I have to give read permission to everyone on folder which the web service application resides. But this causes to folder can be reached and read from everyone.

How can I hide the folder to be seen by everyone in this case?

If I am not successful to describe the issue, I can give you detailed explanations of specific points you want to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I granted read permission for the built-in IUSR account and removed read permission for the everyone. So in this way, anyone on the domain cannot read the folder contents anymore.